# Blender 2.78a AMD GPU support

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, gpu

**EDIT: This is a bug regarding AMD drivers hence the question is marked off topic. There is a report filed in the comments so the devs will tackle it in the next release.**

I leave this here in case others have the same issue. Original question:

When initiating a preview using GPU compute in Cycles, I get a message "errors is console" EDIT: there is the console content. 
Point is, I can't use GPU mode on AMD Radeon 8730M (latest driver). 
Any way to fix this? or am I stuck here? 
OS:
Windows 10 Pro 64 bit, build 1607.
I got help to see the correct console, its content is:

```
OpenCL kernel build output:
"D:\Applications\BlenderFoundation\2.78\scripts\addons\cycles\kernel\kernels/opencl\../../kernel_projection.h", line 238: error:
      expression must have pointer-to-struct-or-union type
            float altitude = fabsf(safe_asinf(D->z));
                             ^

1 error detected in the compilation of "C:\Users\agoston\AppData\Local\Temp\OCL7644T2.cl".
Frontend phase failed compilation.

OpenCL build failed: errors in console
Build error: CL_BUILD_PROGRAM_FAILURE
Device init success
Compiling base_kernel OpenCL kernel ...
Build flags: -D__NODES_MAX_GROUP__=3 -D__NODES_FEATURES__=15 -D__MAX_CLOSURE__=64 -D__NO_HAIR__ -D__NO_OBJECT_MOTION__ -D__NO_CAMERA_MOTION__ -D__NO_BAKING__ -D__NO_PATCH_EVAL__
OpenCL kernel build output:
"D:\Applications\BlenderFoundation\2.78\scripts\addons\cycles\kernel\kernels/opencl\../../kernel_projection.h", line 238: error:
      expression must have pointer-to-struct-or-union type
            float altitude = fabsf(safe_asinf(D->z));
                             ^

1 error detected in the compilation of "C:\Users\agoston\AppData\Local\Temp\OCL7644T3.cl".
Frontend phase failed compilation.

OpenCL build failed: errors in console
Build error: CL_BUILD_PROGRAM_FAILURE
trying to save userpref at C:\Users\agoston\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.78\config\userpref.blend ok
<!> event has invalid window
Device init success
Compiling base_kernel OpenCL kernel ...
Build flags: -D__NODES_MAX_GROUP__=3 -D__NODES_FEATURES__=15 -D__MAX_CLOSURE__=64 -D__NO_HAIR__ -D__NO_OBJECT_MOTION__ -D__NO_CAMERA_MOTION__ -D__NO_BAKING__ -D__NO_PATCH_EVAL__
OpenCL kernel build output:
"D:\Applications\BlenderFoundation\2.78\scripts\addons\cycles\kernel\kernels/opencl\../../kernel_projection.h", line 238: error:
      expression must have pointer-to-struct-or-union type
            float altitude = fabsf(safe_asinf(D->z));
                             ^

1 error detected in the compilation of "C:\Users\agoston\AppData\Local\Temp\OCL7644T4.cl".
Frontend phase failed compilation.

OpenCL build failed: errors in console
Build error: CL_BUILD_PROGRAM_FAILURE
```

Comment: Which OS are you using? How did you open the console? Please edit your question and add the information.

Comment: sorry, doing that right away

Comment: You won't find any hardware-related errors in the Python Console. The correct one is the black DOS-like console that opens after you start Blender. Go to "Menu - Window - Toggle System Console".

Comment: Thanks. I'm checking how to copy from it and add it here.

Comment: See https://developer.blender.org/T49897 . There's already an error filed for this. If you need this urgently, you might want to try a driver downgrade. Otherwise it'll get fixed in the next release.